# Is there something wrong with the way PostgreSQL connects to my database when specifying a parameters object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using Node.js to connect to my PostgreSQL database.

I'm changing the way I create the connection to my PostgreSQL database in order to specify the maximum number of connections.

This is the existing piece of code (I've replaced the actual user/password with user and password; the db name is the same as the user):

```
// Load and initialize pg-promise:
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

let cn = process.env.DATABASE_URL_FULL

// Create the database instance:
const db = pgp(cn);
```

Where `DATABASE_URL_FULL = postgres://user:password@manny.db.elephantsql.com:5432/user`

This works fine. However, when I use this:

```
// Load and initialize pg-promise:
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

// Connection parameters
const cn = {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    max: process.env.DATABASE_MAX_CON,
    idleTimeoutMillis: process.env.DATABASE_IDLE_TIMEOUT
};

// Create the database instance:
const db = pgp(cn);
```

Where `DATABASE_URL = manny.db.elephantsql.com`.

I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres://manny.db.elephantsql.com postgres://manny.db.elephantsql.com:5432
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

Comment: Okay, I noticed that although I had set the environment variable to `manny.db.elephantsql.com`, it was still using `postgres://manny.db.elephantsql.com`

this is very weird. I cleared out my environment variables, rebooted, and set them again. now it is working on my development machine (using the elephantsql url) - next step, test it in my GCP instance.